# How to redirect login urls depending on if the user is admin or not in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-settings

I'm still new to Django. I have an admin user and a regular user who is not an admin. When admin login he should be redirected to '/admin_section' & when a regular user login he should be redirected to the '/' front page. Beyond that, it should be possible for an admin to be able to navigate to the '/' front page and see the page as a regular user can see.

I've been trying to search for an answer for this and the only thing I find is that I can use request.user.is_superuser in a view and ask whether the user is a superuser/admin or not. But the problem then becomes that admin will not have the ability to navigate to the front page ever. I have also set the login_redirect_url to "LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'" which means everytime a user login they will be redirected to the frontpage - but it should not be like that.

Here is my code so far (from the views.py file):

```
def home(request):
   # if the user is not logged-in, show the loginpage
   if not request.user.is_authenticated:
       return HttpResponseRedirect('login')

# if the user is logged-in, show the frontpage
return render(request, 'mainapp/index.html')

# return the view for the admin section
def admin(request):

    # if the user is logged-in & is an admin - show the admin section
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_superuser:
        return render(request, 'mainapp/admin.html')

return redirect('home') # redirects to the home view
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, AccessMixin

# a class which act as a view - it displays the login-form
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm, AccessMixin):
    username=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

urls.py:

```
path('login/', views_auth.LoginView.as_view(form_class=LoginForm, redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'), # login-page
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Create your login view inherited from the built-in login view and override the `get_success_url` method according to your logic.

   ```
    from django.contrib.auth import views as views_auth

    class LoginView(views_auth.LoginView):
        form_class = LoginForm
        redirect_authenticated_user = True

        def get_success_url(self):
            # write your logic here
            if self.request.user.is_superuser:
                return '/admin_section'
            return '/'
   ```

   #### urls.py

   ```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    ]
   ```
2. Provide the newly created view as the login URL in the settings file.

   #### settings.py

   ```
    LOGIN_URL = 'login'
   ```

Comment: I have updated my question with the other files. I have a class for the LoginView already - should I make another class?

Comment: @user3740970 You can use both parameters you are providing with LoginView class I suggested. See LoginView class in updated answer.

Comment: but it is not redirecting to the /admin_section when logging in with a superuser?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - I would add using the super method is wisest - look to the source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py

Comment: @user3740970 - you don't need the LOGIN_URL in settings and verify that the project urls.py is where you're placing the loginview - it should be first in the list

Comment: Almost forgot - don't need the form_class, unless you desire to use that form, but the easiest way to get it running is to copy the login.html to your projects templates/admin/ folder and use template_name = 'admin/login.html' where form_class is